# Create csv file in Cloud Storage using Cloud Functions

Tags: python-3.x, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have been trying to create a csv file from a string in Cloud Functions. It is storing the file temporarily in /tmp folder. Then the file goes to the bucket.

Following is my code -

```
def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_file(source_file_name)

message = "Data for CSV file"
csv = open('test.csv', "w")    #ERROR HERE
csv.write(message)
with open('/tmp/test.csv', 'r') as file_obj:
    upload_blob('test-bucket', file_obj, 'test.csv')
```

I am getting the following error -

```
File "/user_code/main.py", line 30, in hello_main csv = open('test.csv', 
"w") OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'test.csv'
```

How to make this file writable?

Comment: You are not closing the handle for test.csv. The file stays locked so you cannot create and write again. In your design, do not use the /tmp directory. Use in-memory buffering.

Comment: @TeeKay did you find a fix?

Comment: Why did you tag it with google-cloud-platform? it's a question about simple file operations!

Answer (score 4):

As [@saccodd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5118339/saccodd) said the issue is that you only have write permissions in the [`/tmp` directory](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system).  So replacing:

```
csv = open('test.csv', "w")
```

with:

```
csv = open('/tmp/test.csv', "w")
```

would solve the error but it is recommended to close the file before handling it again. Quoting the [Python official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

> It is good practice to use the [with](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) keyword when dealing with file 
>   objects. The advantage is that the file is properly closed after its 
>   suite finishes, even if an exception is raised at some point. Using 
>   with is also much shorter than writing equivalent [try-finally](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#finally) blocks

So better replace

```
csv = open('test.csv', "w") #ERROR HERE 
csv.write(message)
```

with:

```
with open('/tmp/test.csv', "w") as csv: 
    csv.write(message)
```

Comment: I think the use of 'with'  is a minor concern for the question asked. Even more, it is just a temporary file in Cloud Function.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
csv = open('test.csv', "w")
```

with:

```
csv = open('/tmp/test.csv', "w")
```

since you have write permissions only in /tmp